# Raidxpert2 shows disks but won't enable them

Tags: windows-10, raid

I have a Gigabyte X399 motherboard with Raid enabled. I have 2x250gb SSDs in RAID 0 with Windows installed. These two drives operate as expected.

I have another 2 SSD drives both 240gb and a 1TB drive.

All the drives are detected in the BIOS and show up in Raidxpert, however other than the RAID0 and 1 of the SSD drives none are "Active".

How to I make these drives active? Please see the screenshots below:
[image: Computer Management/Disk Management]

[image: Raidxpert2]

Comment: Array 2 and Array 3 are offline because no matching disks are inserted. Have you tampered the drives in any way? Moved them around SATA ports?

Comment: Yes it appears I switched the SATA ports during some cable rearranging. I deleted the offline arrays and it automatically recreated them with the actual disks.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I switched the SATA ports on these drives after installing them (rearranged the cabling in my case).

To fix the issue I deleted the offline arrays (I unplugged the drives first to be 100% it wouldn't wipe them), restarted, recreated them and everything was fine and dandy.